# Model Attribute Won't Update, Validation Error Called On Separate Attribute Not Being Updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following semi-advanced DB query that is going through hourly prices for the last 10 years and returning daily average prices for the last seven days:

```
averages = Trade.where('date >= ?', 7.days.ago).average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date - INTERVAL '1 hour')")
```

This returns the `date` (for that day) and an `averageprice` like this:

```
"2012-12-29 00:00:00"=>#<BigDecimal:7f97932be328,'0.2513458333 33333333E2',27(27)>
```

I then loop through each response and save them as new records in a TradeDailyAverage Model.

```
    # Loops through each daily average produced above 
    averages.each do |date, avg|

     # Converts the BigDecimal to Floating Point(?)
     averagefloat = avg.to_f

     # Rounds the Daily Average to only two decimal points
     dailyaverage = number_with_precision(averagefloat, :precision => 2)

     # Creates a new Object in the PpDailyAverage table  
     TradeDailyAverage.create(date: date, averageprice: dailyaverage)
```

This works, but since this will be an hourly **Rake Task**, with new prices coming in every hour, how can I change this to first find a TradeDailyAverage by `date` and if it exists, update the `averageprice` attribute, or create a new record if it doesn't exist.

Validate_uniqueness is set on TradeDailyAverage Model.

**Update**

When I do this, 7 items appear, with accurate averages.  But they just won't save.  When I add `newaverage.save!` I get a **"Validation Error: Date has already been taken!"**

```
 newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date: date)
          newaverage.averageprice = dailyaverage
          puts newaverage.date
          puts newaverage.averageprice
```

Also, if I do newaverage.new_record? Ever average returns TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (thanks to Alex's help) was due to a difference in the datetimes.  Upon saving to a PG db, the hour would change on the datetime.  This may be due to a timezone issue in the db.  So, the code above could not find existing records, since it contained a different hourly time than what has been saved in the database.

Since I am producing daily averages, I don't need the time, just the date in the date column.  So, I converted my dates to date to avoid the time difference issue.  Also I changed the code a bit with a Case, so that I can report errors.  I don't think this is very efficient, but it is working for now.  I believe Alex's solution above may also work as long as the datetime values are converted to dates with `.to_date`:

```
# Loops through each daily average produced above 
    averages.each do |datetime, avg|

    # Converts the BigDecimal to Floating Point(?)
    avgfloat = avg.to_f

    # Rounds the Daily Average to only two decimal points
    avgprice = number_with_precision(avgfloat, :precision => 2)

    # Converts datetime to date since this will not work with datetime (PostgreSQL is time-zoned challenged)    
    avgdate  = datetime.to_date

        # These are printed to use for testing. 
      puts avgdate
      puts avgprice

      # Starts Case to either report an error, update an existing record, or create new.
      case

        when avgdate.blank? || avgprice.blank?
            puts "Something went terribly wrong with your seven day averages producing algorithm."

        when TradeDailyAverage.exists?(:date=>avgdate)
            updateavg = TradeDailyAverage.find_by_date(avgdate)
            updateavg.averageprice = avgprice
            updateavg.save

        else
            TradeDailyAverage.create(:date=>avgdate, :averageprice=>avgprice)

        end # Ends Case  

    end # Ends Loop for each Daily Average
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want something like this:

```
tda = TradeDailyAverage.first_or_initialize(date: date)
tda.averageprice = dailyaverage
tda.save
```

Comment: To test this, I emptied my TradeDailyAverage table to see if this would create new records. But, the result is that it only creates one record (instead of records for each of the last 7 days).

Comment: Those three lines of mine are a replacement for the `create` statement at the last line of your code. So if you're not getting the expected number of TradeDailyAverage entries, it may be a problem with how you're generating the `averages` array. Are you sure it's producing seven items?

Comment: I've updated the post.  The averages are generated seamlessly, but I cannot save since I am getting the Data Validation above.

Comment: I can see how that would be frustrating. To me, one candidate problem would be that `date` (as defined in `averages.each`) is not actually matching a value stored on the database (thus, you get a new record). But when it comes time to save, ActiveRecord is converting it into a value that *does* match what's already in the database, and then validation fails. Is the `pp_daily_averages.date` column defined as a date, or a datetime?

Comment: pp_daily_averages.date is defined as datetime, not date.  What should I do differently?  P.s.Thanks for your continued help :)

Comment: If you define the date column as a date, rather than a datetime, I think the `first_or_initialize` call will pull back your record correctly. That's the best idea I have for why it works in my test environment but not on yours.