# Find_or_initialize_by Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a DB Table for a Model entitled TradeDailyAverage.  It has a `date` (DateTime) & `averageprice` (decimal) column

When I run this, I can't get the averageprice attribute to update:

```
      newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
      newaverage.update_attributes :averageprice => dailyaverage
```

Further, when I run this, the date will show up, but the averageprice will not show up in rails console.  It only shows up as blank:

```
newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
          puts newaverage.averageprice
          puts newaverage.date
```

Is there anything special that I need to do to averageprice before I save it?

**Here is all of the entire Rake Task for your reference:**

```
averages = Trade.where('date >= ?', 7.days.ago).average(:price, :group => "DATE_TRUNC('day', date - INTERVAL '1 hour')")

    # Loops through each daily average produced above 
    averages.each do |date, avg|

    # Converts the BigDecimal to Floating Point(?)
    averagefloat = avg.to_f

    # Rounds the Daily Average to only two decimal points
    dailyaverage = number_with_precision(averagefloat, :precision => 2)

      newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
      newaverage.update_attributes :averageprice => dailyaverage
```

Comment: This seems like a continuation of the problem you listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162771.

The code you've listed should work, and I've been able to run it a test application in my local environment. You may want to try calling `update_attributes!` to see if there's a validation error that's preventing these instances from being saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex.  Upon calling update_attributes, I get the following error in rails console:  Validation failed: Date has already been taken
/Users/austen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'

Comment: But, I don't want to change the date, just update the averageprice attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was simply that upon saving to my database, PostgreSQL was changing the hourly time, possibly due to a timezone issue.  Thus, all of my instances above were new, and I couldn't update attributes of an existing model.  So, I converted my datetime data to dates, changed my date db column to date instead of datetime, and now everything is working smoothly.  Yves gives some great info above though which helped me later on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `find_or_initialize_by` you need to think carefully about the implications. Lets take your first example:

```
  newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
  newaverage.update_attributes :averageprice => dailyaverage
```

This should work, when the `TradeDailyAverage` for the given `date` is already in the database. It should not work however, when you get a new record back. The reason is simply because a new record is not persisted to the database. There is no way for `update_attributes` to update a non persisted record. You have two options here:

1.) Do not use `update_attributes` but assign the value and call `save`. This works for both, new and created records:

```
  newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
  newaverage.averageprice = dailyaverage
  newaverage.save
```

2.) Do not use `find_or_initialize_by` but `find_or_create_by`. This way if the record does not exist, a new one is directly written to the database. Now `update_attributes` should work because you always get persisted records back. Note that this approach has the drawback that you save records without an `averageprice` to the database. I would not recommend that.

The explanation above should also explain your second example:

```
newaverage = TradeDailyAverage.find_or_initialize_by_date(date)
puts newaverage.averageprice
puts newaverage.date
```

This should output the `averageprice` and the date for persisted records. If you get a newly initialized record back though, it will only display the date. Since you only initialized the record with a date object, there is no way that the `averageprice` is already set.